# S5- Stuck in bootloop

Tags: boot

I somehow deleted my ADB shell (of rooted S5) in superuser and then I was trying to flash it back. And because I didn't backup my root I ended up with it saying:

> KERNEL IS NOT SEANDROID ENFORCING
>
> SET WARRANTY BIT : kernel....

I can't seem to get it to go back! What should I do resolve this issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have flashed a custom kernel. You should reinstall the ROM on your phone. Go to www.sammobile.com/firmwares and download the appropriate one for your device and then flash it with ODIN.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. Io did exactly as you said . It worked and i actually flashed 5.0 from 4.4.2 and i quite like it. But now I have lost Root access but the phone still says its rooted!I also think my S5 is slower and freezes alot!

Comment: Did you factory reset your phone while upgrading? I also have an s5 and updated it to lollipop, had a lot of crashes etc. until I factory resetted it.